# Hibernate slf4j exception

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting the following exception when I call
`configuration.configure(hibernate.cfg.xml).buildSessionFactory()`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.<clinit>(NullableType.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.Hibernate.<clinit>(Hibernate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.<clinit>(TypeFactory.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ManyToOne.getType(ManyToOne.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ManyToOne.createForeignKey(ManyToOne.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createProperty(HbmBinder.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2060)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:702)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:599)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    at com.enwelib.server.hibernate.helper.HibernateVendHelper.<init>(HibernateVendHelper.java:47)
    at com.ensarm.crawler.CrawlManager.saveEntity(CrawlManager.java:93)
    at com.ensarm.crawler.CrawlManager.main(CrawlManager.java:30)
```

Answer (score 5):

The method [`Logger.isTraceEnabled()`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#isTraceEnabled%28%29) was added in [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) 1.4. Apparently you are using an older one while Hibernate requires more recent version. Revise your CLASSPATH and use newer version of this library (currently 1.6.4).

Comment: i am using slf4j api 1.6.0 and slf4j jcl 1.6.0 still its giving me same problem

Comment: @pallavi: which version of Hibernate are you using? How do you run/package your application?

Comment: I am using hibernate 3.0 and I have simple java application with com.ensarm.crawler.domain where all domain classes are and hibernate.cfg.xml  is under com.ensarm.crawler package

Comment: Thomasz' answer sounds accurate. I'd check you classpath for an older version of slf4j-api.